The build time displayed by the js file generated by npm build is inconsistent with the system time zone
jenkins@71d539d1d825:/tmp/tmp/exchange-h5$ head -1  dist/assets/details-BKMtEiDY.js 
/* Bundle Time: Mon Dec 16 2024 10:03:35 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) */
jenkins@71d539d1d825:/tmp/tmp/exchange-h5$ date
Mon Dec 16 18:15:27 CST 2024

Why the time zone of the js file is inconsistent with the system time zone, I want to know where the time zone of the js file comes from, I can provide more information if necessary，thanks
My command is (sh)
export NVM_DIR="/var/jenkins_home/.nvm"
[ -s "\$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "\$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm use 20
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com
npm install
npm run build:test

I have no clue because I don't know enough about npm. I hope the js file can use the system time zone or the time zone I specify.

is the time wrong at all? the time zone I specify - where did you specify a timezone?

If the build finished 12 minutes ago, and your timezone is China Standard Time, then that's the correct time. It's simply presented in the UTC timezone, but why's that a problem?
